# Extract Model from a BackboneJS Collection/UnderscoreJS array

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, models, underscore.js

I've been checking the docs of Backbone and Underscore for a "proper" way to extract a model (remove the value and have it returned) from a collection.  I know I can do this through direct access via the "models" array attribute and the splice method, but is that stepping around some built-in way I'm overlooking?

Comment: what do you mean by "extract a model"?  Numerous methods are provided for retrieving a specific instance from a collection.  For example: in Backbone, `myCollection.get(some_id)` would retrieve the model instance having the specified id.  The Underscore method `find()` (a.k.a. "detect()") can be used to search for, and retrieve instances based on user-specified criteria.  Are you looking for something more complicated than that?

Comment: Yes, I can identify the item without a problem, but I'm looking to actually remove the model at say index 5 and have that value returned.  I can do this using the splice method directly on the models array, but I was looking for something a little more slick working through the framework if it existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> I'm looking to actually remove the model at say index 5 and have that value returned.

Try this:

```
// given: myCollection is a Backbone collection

var item = myCollection.at(5);
myCollection.remove(item);

// ... now, do whatever else with `item`...
```

Answer (score 3):

It is critical that you use the built-in "remove" method on the collection.  Remove does the following:

- updates the built-in index that's used for collection.getByCid()
- updates the built-in index that's used for collection.get()
- decrements collection.length
- removes the model (or models if you pass in an array of models, ids, or cids)
- triggers the remove event on the collection

If you manipulate the models inside the collection directly, none of the things above will happen.

More info on remove: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-remove

Comment: Thanks for the details.  The explanation likely saved a bunch of headache for down the line.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how the caching works w/ backbone, but does that mean I shouldn't touch the "models" array?  For example, will reordering them kill the caching, or is that this an accepted operation?

Comment: you should consider the `models` array to be read-only.  Don't add, remove, or re-order items in this array.  There are methods on the backbone collection object for performing all these tasks - use those instead.

Comment: I should have just called it an "Index" instead of "Index/Cache", because it's really just an "index".  Backbone builds a couple of indices inside the collection so that every time you call collection.get() or collection.getByCid(), it can simply use the index to find and return the model instead of looping through all of the models. Like Lee said, the best practice is to never touch the models directly.